# Issues with running log4net

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, log4net

I am trying to run log4net in ASP.NET Core application and so far got an issue.

I got second line in my appsettings.json

```
"log4netConfig": "log4net\\logConfiguration.xml"
```

and this in Startup.cs

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(string.Concat(env.ContentRootPath, @"\", loggingConfig["log4netConfig"])));
```

Seems working, at least on local machine, but after publishing it, I receive second error:

```
Failed to find configuration section 'log4net' in the application's .config file. Check your .config file for the <log4net> and <configSections> elements. The configuration section should look like: <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
```

So... as I understand, configuration wasn't founded.
I also have hand made logger for all project which contains `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` and this is very bad for those kind of things as I understand (it used to work normally until I needed to move log4net file path in appsettings.json.

What can I change to make this thing work properly?

Comment: Does log4net support .Net Core?

Comment: Does this file exist `new FileInfo(string.Concat(env.ContentRootPath, @"\", loggingConfig["log4netConfig"]))` ? i.e. are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: I used to run it in different way. Just `<add key="log4net.Config"` in app.config and configuration file and it works with `XmlConfigurator.Configure()`. Well, now I'm trying to move this call inside appsettings.json.

Comment: Yes, file exist (and as I mentioned, I can rut this on local machine at least)

Comment: And does the user under which IIS is running have access to the file?

Comment: Yep, it does. So far I think that it simply cant receive data from appsettings.json, but I could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem ended up being something like that:

`XmlConfigurator.Configure()` was inside my own logger, and logger was added with `.AddSingleton` in Startup.cs. It appeared that logger tried to find log4net.config key in app.config (which is no longer exist) and it ended up being this issue.

I changed configuration call and boom, no more errors...